# Как получить JSON из HTML?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

Есть HTML куски (назовем их так), которые генерирует WYSIWYG редактор. Появилась необходимость конвертировать эти HTML коды в JSON.

HTML в таблице БД лежит такого вида (отступы добавил для наглядности):

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>12313</td>
            <td>12313</td>
            <td>1313</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123123</td>
            <td>123123</td>
            <td>123123</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p><br></p>
<p>123123123</p>
<p><br></p>
<h6 class="text-center">
    <strong>
        <em>
            <del>
                <u>
                    <span style="color: #c0504d;">
                        <u>123123123</u>
                    </span>
                </u>
            </del>
        </em>
    </strong>
</h6>
<p><br></p>
<p>13123123123</p>
```

Нужно получить JSON примерно такого вида:

```
{
    table: {
        tbody: {
            // ...
        }
    },
    p: ['br'],
    p: '123123123',
    // ...
}
```

Есть ли какое-нибудь готовое решение?

Comment: На кой горящий чёрт это в принципе может быть нужно? :D

Comment: @D-side есть один момент в проекте, который этого требует :))

Comment: Это сейчас не сказало абсолютно ничего :)

Comment: @D-side попробовал сделать с помощью Nokogiri: `Hash.from_xml(html.to_xml).to_json`. Но он выдает ошибку: `REXML::ParseException: Missing end tag for 'br' (got "p")`.

Comment: Как минимум потому, что это у вас не XML, а HTML. Внезапно, HTML не является XML-совместимым.

Comment: @D-side но если удалить все `<br>`, то все работает как надо, получаю JSON нужного вида.

Comment: А если не `to_xml` а `to_xhtml`?

Comment: @D-side блин. Заново расставил отступы в редакторе, то есть заново сгенерировались `<p><br></p><p><br></p>` и теперь все нормально работает. В JSON отображается как `{\"br\":null}`.

Comment: @D-side в данный момент работают оба примера.

Comment: `.to_xhtml` заставляет работать и на исходной разметке. Потому что превращает `<br>` в `<br />`, самозакрывающиеся теги, с которыми в XML, в отличие от `<br>`. проблем не возникает. UPD: но я б на вашем месте всерьёз задумался, **зачем**.

Comment: @D-side супер, спасибо! :) Судя по ошибке это то что и нужно было.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно попробовать разобрать HTML-код при помощи Nokogiri (входит в состав Rails)

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'active_support/all'

str = <<HERE
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>12313</td>
            <td>12313</td>
            <td>1313</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123123</td>
            <td>123123</td>
            <td>123123</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
<p>123123123</p>
<p></p>
<p>13123123123</p>
HERE

page = Nokogiri::HTML(str)

puts Hash.from_xml(page.to_xml).to_json
```

Единственное, у него парсер немного капризный и возможно придется пошаманить с 
 тэгами. После разбора вы можете преобразовать дерево в Nokogiri в XML, а его средствами ActiveSupport (тоже входит в состав Rails) преобразовать в json:

```
{"html":
  {"body":
    {"table":
      {"class": "table",
        "tbody":
           {"tr":
             [
               {"td":["12313","12313","1313"]},
               {"td":["123123","123123","123123"]}
             ]
           }
       },
     "p": [null,"123123123",null,"13123123123"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Блин, прочитал комментарии к вопросу, оказывается решили точно так же )))